# Random access to an encrypted file and write encrypted data into a specific offset in Android

Tags: android, encryption, aes

I have a library which provides resulting data using callbacks. I then write data to a file by first AES encrypting using CipherOutputStream. Unfortunately, it also seems that this library needs to seek back into already provided (and written) data to change it. Can I do this somehow on the encrypted file?

It is my understanding that this might be possible with some algorithms, like AES ECB, which should be supported on Android. Is this correct or am I wrong?

Let's say the library asks me to seek to an offset of 40 bytes and to write some bytes, how can I do this, if possible?

Answer (score -1):

The whole file has to be re-encrypted, with a new initialization vector, every time it is changed. Any other approach is insecure.

ECB mode supports random access without re-encryption, but ECB does not satisfy the "secure" requirement *per se*. CBC mode does not support random access. CTR mode does support random access, but you must never use it this way, because it counts as nonce reuse, which results in plaintext recovery.

Comment: Can you explain better "but ECB does not satisfy the "secure" requirement per se"?

Comment: ECB leaks a lot of information about the plaintext. Wikipedia has a pretty good explanation of some of its shortcomings: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29

Comment: I know that article already, it is the reason I asked about ECB in the first place. So, assuming it is sufficiently secure for my specific situation, what is the best approach?

Comment: ECB is not sufficiently secure for anything – there's no reason to even consider it. The only secure way is to re-encrypt the whole file, and this is how everyone else does it too.